# How to use caret in lookbehind in Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find all separate words "is" in

```
"is this is that this that this that this is"
```

This finds is everywhere I need except beginning

`(?<= )is(?= |$)`

This leads to error with parenthesis https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/22:

`(?<=^| )is(?= |$)`

How to lookbehind beginning of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookback assertions in Python need to be fixed width.  Meaning, you cannot use `(?<=^| )` which matches the start of the string (0 characters) or a space (1 character).

To do what you want, try using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> import re
>>> data = "is this is that this that this that this is"
>>> re.findall(r'\bis\b', data)
['is', 'is', 'is']
>>>
```

Note that [`\b`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) matches a word boundary.

Comment: I really need to match independent ocurances of "is":  with spaces or begin/end string on sides. I need not match "this"

Comment: This is nice. Just need to add capturing group or nothing will be captured. `\b(is)\b`